# Multiplying a vector and a matrix's rows

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

I have a square matrix $N\times N$: $$A_{ij}=a_{ij}S_i \text{ [no sum over repeated index] }$$

and I want to decompose it in the form:

$$A=BC$$ where $$B_{ij}=B_{ij}(S_1,S_2,...,S_N)\ \ \ ,\ \ \ C_{ij}=a_{ij}$$

In other words: having a N-component vector $\bf{S}$ and a square matrix $N\times N$, say C, what is the operation that allows me to multiply the $i$-th row of $C$ by $S_i$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pre-multiply the matrix by the diagonal matrix with $S_i$ on the diag. For example, suppose we have a matrix:
$$A =
\begin{pmatrix}
  a_{11} & a_{12} & \cdots & a_{1N} \\
  \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
  a_{N1} & a_{N2} & \cdots & a_{NN} \\
 \end{pmatrix}
$$
and a diagonal matrix 
$$S =
\begin{pmatrix}
  S_{1} & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
  0 & S_{2} & 0 & \cdots \\
  \vdots  &   & \ddots & \vdots \\
  0 & \cdots & 0 & S_{N} \\
 \end{pmatrix}
$$
then the pre-multiplication of $S$ gives
$$ SA =
\begin{pmatrix}
  S_1 a_{11} & S_1 a_{12} & \cdots & S_1 a_{1N} \\
  \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
  S_N a_{N1} & S_N a_{N2} & \cdots & S_N a_{NN} \\
 \end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: Could you please explicit that?